# Inserting TIFF file in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, convert, geotiff-tiff

I have toposheet in .PDF format and I have converted it into tiff using ArcGIS 10.3 conversion tool.

When I try to insert tiff file it is not showing in output folder.![image]

Comment: The Default.gdb folder is what's called a file geodatabase. It's not like a normal Windows folder full of files that you can interact with individually. You can't interact with the contents of a geodatabase with Windows Explorer, you need to use ArcCatalog.

Comment: How to add my tiff file in arccatalog

Comment: Open ArcCatalog, then connect to the folder that contains your geodatabase

Comment: My file is in default.gdb folder should I move that file anywhere else or I can connect deafult.gdb folder in arccatalog

Comment: Did you try just adding the extension ".TIFF" to the filename? It looks like you just didn't specify a file extension when you converted the file. If you converted PDF to TIFF you don't really need to mess around with geodatabases at all, you can use the add data button as whyzar suggests. You need to add the correct file extension to your converted file though.

Comment: Ok I will try that

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [add data button/tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/adding-and-connecting-data-and-tools.htm) [image] as you typically would use to add a shapefile or raster format dataset (e.g. tif file).

You might need to just refresh your folder, create a new folder connection, or try going back one level in your current folder connection and then try adding the tiff file once more.

Comment: Should I have to add that file to arccatalog ?

Comment: Not necessarily, if you could provide screen shots of where your tiff file was saved that may help us figure this out with you.

Comment: Mouse cursor is pointing the file which I have converted. It is in Arcgis default.gdb folder

Comment: You will need to open an ArcMap document, then click on the add data button, connect to the folder and add the tiff

Comment: I have already connect the folder but still not showing tiff file

Comment: Join the chat so we can work through it - https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66236/how-to-insert-tiff-file-in-arcmap

Comment: How to chat there in that chat rooms

Comment: My reputation is low so I can't. Chat there